# .htaccess multiple conditions for RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What I actually want to do:

- domain example.com must be accessible only from 5 specified IP's (whitelist)
- url example.com/example/test must be accessible from all IP

Trying to write in .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1.1.1.1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^2.2.2.2 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^3.3.3.3 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^4.4.4.4 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example/test$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [R=403,L]
```

Condition in pseudo code looks like

```
IF REMOTE_ADDR IS NOT (1.1.1.1 OR 2.2.2.2 OR 3.3.3.3 OR 4.4.4.4 OR 127.0.0.1) AND REQUEST_URI IS NOT /example/test THEN ACCESS DENIED
```

`.htaccess` file is valid and condition looks like logic, where can be problem, because in every request I get `403` response

(IP address are not real, I'm changed to fake for security reason)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Allow /example/test 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/example/test$ 
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Allow access to rest of the site to  5 IPs 
RewriteCond "%{REMOTE_ADDR}" "!=1\.0\.0\.1"     
# Example IP6 address
RewriteCond "%{REMOTE_ADDR}" "!=::2" 
RewriteCond "%{REMOTE_ADDR}" "!=3\.3\.3\.3" 
RewriteCond "%{REMOTE_ADDR}" "!=4\.4\.4\.4"
RewriteCond "%{REMOTE_ADDR}" "!=5\.5\.5\.5"
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]

# Arrive to app.php
RewriteRule .? app.php [L]
```

Comment: Here is problem in `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` because now I get 404 because is not direct url and must be rewritten by `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]` how I can fix that ?

Comment: @Wizard do you want requests from 5 allowed IP addresses to arrive to app.php ?

Comment: That's simple, add RewriteRule .? app.php [L]

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example/test$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.1\.1\.1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^2\.2\.2\.2
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^3\.3\.3\.3
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^4\.4\.4\.4
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1 
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^ app.php [L]
```

Comment: url example.com/example/test is not accesible from everywhere I try with vpn and getting 403 forbidden

Comment: You are trying to block only `/example/test` ?

Comment: I want have only public access for '/example/test' and other to be accessible  from provided IP addresses

Comment: OK, I change for that.